# WebStorm auto upload on file save

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I have established an SFTP connecting between my WebStorm and host.

How can I configure WebStorm to autoupload the current file to the server when I hit save?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure that this deployment entry you have configured is **marked as Default for this project** (as auto upload will work for default entry only)
2. `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment | Options`
3. `Upload changed files automatically to the default server` -- choose another option than `Never`.

You can read more about deployment in [this official manual/how-to](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm) -- it's for PhpStorm and written for older version but it's exactly the same for all JetBrains' IDEs (just slightly different path to the actual settings).

Answer (score 0):

Open the settings with `Ctrl + ,` or `Cmd + ,`.

In the search bar to the top, type in `Upload changed` and it should take you to the Deployment -> Options page.  There, you can choose to upload automatically, upload on explicit save (with `Ctrl + S` or `Cmd + S`), or don't automatically upload.